# Не могу разобраться с циклами for, while. Постоянно ошибка out of range

Tags: python, for, while, task, range

Дана задача:
Напишите программу, которая считывает с консоли числа (по одному в строке) до тех пор, пока сумма введённых чисел не будет равна 0 и сразу после этого выводит сумму квадратов всех считанных чисел.

Гарантируется, что в какой-то момент сумма введённых чисел окажется равной 0, после этого считывание продолжать не нужно.

В примере мы считываем числа 1, -3, 5, -6, -10, 13; в этот момент замечаем, что сумма этих чисел равна нулю и выводим сумму их квадратов, не обращая внимания на то, что остались ещё не прочитанные значения.

Я написал код(не до конца, потому что не могу разобраться даже с циклом), если можно, то ОБЬЯСНИТЕ КАК ИМЕННО РАБОТАЕТ ЦИКЛ, КАК ЭТО ИСПРАВИТЬ И КАК ДОРАТОТАТЬ ПРОГРАММУ(без более сложных конструкций, методов и функций)

```
    list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
_sum = 0
_true = True

while _true == True:
    for x in list:
        if x > 0:
            list[x] + list[x+1]
            _sum += x
            if _sum == 0:
                _true = False
                break
print(_sum)
```

Comment: вы не можете прочитать все числа сразу, потому что не знаете, сколько их. читайте в цикле по одному числу и выхидите, когда сумма станет рана нулю

Comment: Числа вам даются по одному в строке, а не в одной строке все сразу.

Comment: Строчка list[x] + list[x] ничего не делает. Переменная _true не нужна. Проверка if x > 0 вообще лишняя. range() выдаёт вам числа больше 0, зачем это ещё раз проверять...

Comment: вот как это все исправить? я просто не пойму? я знаю, что она не выполняет своих функций, но я писал ее именно с целью сделать поэлементное чтение из списка. но я просто не знаю как

Comment: Разбейте задачу на малые понятные подзадачи и ешьте слона кусочками. Как идти циклом по списку описано в каждом учебнике по питону.

Comment: спасибо за советы)

Comment: а что не так с этой строкой можете подсказать? list[x] + list[x]

Comment: Складывает элемент списка с ним же (т.е. просто умножает на 2), но результат никуда не присваивается, т.е. просто пропадает. Да и в задаче нет ничего про умножение на 2, зачем вы это вообще производите?

Comment: как же пропалает? а как же переменная _sum, в которую плюсуются значения х? я изменил код, но эта строка все равно не работает

Comment: Если вы вот так на ходу будете менять код, о котором речь, то ещё и не такое может случиться. Строчка list[x] + list[x+1] что у вас делает?

Comment: прибавляет текущий индекс к следующему индексу, а в следующей итерации цикла x будет уже иметь на +1 большее значение индекса. Ну, это как я хотел бы, но понимаю, что этот код совершенно не выполняет задуманой функции

Comment: Возьмите учебник. Вы путаете базовые вещи. И перечитайте мой комментарий выше про присвоение.

Comment: я понял, огромное спасибо за разьяснения. Последний вопрос: сколько Вам лет если не секрет? просто интересно стало. Больше не буду Вас больше нагружать глупыми вопросами.

Comment: спросите лучше себя сколько вам лет, что вы пишите как школьник будто наугад, что-нибудь напишу, вдруг сработает

Comment: весьма и весьма грубо с Вашей стороны

Comment: складывается впечатление, будто Вы чем-то недовольны или вовсе оскорблены

Comment: я бы не сказал, что пишу наугад, просто мое мышление и моя логика не совпали с синтаксисом, я не оправдываюсь, понимаю что не правильно пишк кодЮ но все же не наугад, а основываясь хоть на какой-то логике. другое дело, что мышлению для  программирования и пайтона в частности нужно учиться, но Вы могли бы так и написать, хоть сколько-то конструктивно, вместо "нелогичный школьник, пишущий код наугад"

Answer (score 0):

Эта строка всегда выдаст выход за границы списка

```
for x in range(len(list) + 1):
```

Потому что элемента с номером len(lst) ни в одном списке не существует. +1 здесь лишнее.

Comment: а что в таком случае делать?

Comment: В каком случае?

Comment: что делать с этой строкой? и со всем остальным кодом в частности

Comment: Вы, когда писали эту строку, чем руководствовались написав +1?  А так я же написал, что +1 — лишнее. Раз лишнее, значит, надо убрать.

Comment: у меня проблема именно со следующей строчкой list[x] + list[x]

Comment: С этой строчкой не может быть проблем, потому что она ни на что вообще не влияет.

Comment: так в этом, собственно, и проблема)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вот ее решение:

```py
nums = []

while True:
    # Получаем ввод от пользователя
    num = int(input('Enter num: '))
    # Добавляем его в список значений
    nums.append(num)

    # Проверяем не равна ли сумма всех чисел 0
    if sum(nums) == 0:
        break # Если равна - выходим из цикла

sum_nums = 0

# Считаем сумму квадратов всех чисел
for num in nums:
    sum_nums += num ** 2 

# Выводим результат
print(f'Result: {sum_nums}')
```